# Get view and watch time history of any youtube video

Tags: youtube, youtube-api

Is it possible to find watch time and view history of any youtube video through youtube API ? If yes than how ? and if no, then please tell any alternative to it.thanks

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it through API. Just use the [`Videos: list`](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) of the YouTube Data API. Use `statistics` as your part parameter and just place the videoId of the video that you want to get in the `id` parameter.

Here is the sample request.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=statistics&id=y64OsZNYhp0&_h=2&

And this is the response that you will get.

```json
{
 "kind": "youtube#videoListResponse",
 "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/qVhz5oG-YjkUw2MI_dGWHLSoyqw\"",
 "pageInfo": {
  "totalResults": 1,
  "resultsPerPage": 1
 },
 "items": [
  {


   "kind": "youtube#video",
   "etag": "\"uQc-MPTsstrHkQcRXL3IWLmeNsM/tNAz0qXkqB5wXksK0L-_QxgvMKI\"",
   "id": "y64OsZNYhp0",
   "statistics": {
    "viewCount": "1452334",
    "likeCount": "11181",
    "dislikeCount": "136",
    "favoriteCount": "0",
    "commentCount": "1865"
   }
  }
 ]
}
```

To get the watch time or duration of the video, include the `contentDetails` as your part to get the duration.

Here is the sample request for that.

https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/youtube/v3/youtube.videos.list?part=contentDetails%252Cstatistics&id=y64OsZNYhp0&_h=10&

Comment: can we still get the watch time? In contentDetails I see duration but not watch time.

Comment: You may need to use Reports: Query - https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/reference/reports/query

Comment: unfortunately Reports: Query doesnt contain real-time information; only data from complete days are returned, I think?

Answer (score 0):

You can see limited statistics of videos on YouTube that aren't owned by you. To do this, click on the 'More' link underneath a video title and click 'Statistics.

[image]

Comment: the question asks about getting the info through the api. An API is a way for code and scripts to query for data, without going through a web interface.